# MassTransit not receiving Azure ServiceBus Topic Messages

Tags: c#, .net, azureservicebus, servicebus, masstransit

I'm monitoring the topic and subs and messages are getting in, however my masstransit consumer is not receiving anything.

Here's how it's been setup:

```
var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(
                        cfg =>
                        {
                            var azSbHost = cfg.Host(new Uri(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("ServiceBus.Url"))
                                , host =>
                                {
                                    host.TokenProvider = TokenProvider
                                        .CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider
                                        (CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("ServiceBus.SharedAccessKeyName"),
                                            CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("ServiceBus.AccessKey"),
                                            TokenScope.Namespace);                                    
                                });

                            cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(azSbHost,
                                e =>
                                {
                                    e.Consumer<PingConsumer>();
                                });
                            //azSbHost.
                        });
```

The Ping Consumer:

```
public class PingConsumer : IConsumer<Ping>
{
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Ping> pingContext)
    {
        pingContext.Respond(new Pong
        {
            Message = "Pong: " + pingContext.Message.Message
        });
    }
}
```

And the sender:

```
           var pong = await _bus.CreatePublishRequestClient<Ping, Pong>(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),null ).Request(
            new Ping {Message = "Ping: " + message});
```

In Azure, I'm seeing my message count climbing up and not going down. So messages are getting to the queue, but consumer is not consuming the message.

Comment: this question deserves more love and attention

Answer (score 1):

I was missing a VERY important key call to make it all work on both client and server side.

Bus.Start

Comment: That would do it, glad you figured it out.

Comment: Completely my omission :( But yeah thankfully it seems to work out. I do wish there's more end to end Azure example. The few that exists uses the now outdated Azure MassTransit plugin and MT v2 instead of the latest v3. Great framework though!.